# What to do with an awkward colleague?

Tags: colleagues

One of our colleagues is difficult to work with. They can be obnoxious , rude and quick to complain.

In the team they are working in, people are afraid of them and when there is any confrontational situation, people will concede to avoid escalating further. When there are situations where a decision needs to be made, colleague always gets their way otherwise will kick up a stink.

The issue is where the colleague is good at what they do , where the company needs them to meet targets. Colleague knows this and if anyone has the courage to stand up to them they will threaten the company with leaving.

For that reason management and everyone else lets them get away with their behaviour. For example they will pick and choose which working agreements apply to them which everyone else follows.

The issue I have in my role is where I’m responsible for giving guidance to the team over their working practices but because of this colleague I sometimes find them to be obstructive. They can override team decisions. Follow process when it suits them and quick to criticize others. Spoken to my boss about them but my boss just lets them be for reasons mentioned.

Any advice on how to deal with people like this?

Comment: Let them go is the obvious answer. No matter how good they are, the harm to the team is evident.

Comment: Crossed my mind. None of my managers have the balls to make that decision.

Comment: Which, of course, only harms the team even more. Sorry you are in this situation.

Comment: In one ear out the other for me. They totally annoy me though.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere no that is another one, we no longer work together and I’ve had peace of mind since. On a wider note, as you can probably see from some of my posts , there are quite a few toxic people within the working environment. Trying to navigate them can be tricky.

Comment: You're saying "colleague". That implies you aren't in their management chain. That means your options are talking to management, trying to work with them directly as a peer to fix it, or declaring it Someone Else's Problem it Someone Else's Problem and ignoring or avoiding them (perhaps transferring to a position where you don't have to deal with them, or as a last resort finding a job elsewhere).  If there are "quite a few toxic people", that is abnormal and leaving seems the best option... assuming that this really is the case rather than your needing to recalibrate your own expectations.

Comment: I have no line management duties, role is closely aligned to a Scrum Master. The actual Managers here tend to avoid dealing with complex situations since it’s the easiest thing to do. So when people become rogue and toxic they end up taking full advantage of it. Problem with my role given that I have no authority, is I’m highly dependent on not rocking the boat, otherwise team will turn against me and become less responsive.

Comment: @bobo2000 - How impactful are these deviations of these  agreements.  Are they are annoying or do they actually prevent work being performed? Trying to understand if the approach the individual is taking or if it's the actual deviations that are the actual problem. The human behavior is better left to their manager.

Comment: Split the team and let him work alone.

Comment: @Donald work is generally still getting done. The impact is on team dynamics. Tense working environment and sometimes the communication can be disjointed making it harder to facilitate, because colleague can’t be bothered to attend a meeting to give one example

Comment: Is he *actually* good at what he does, or has he simply engineered himself a position where he's the only person with critical knowledge (either by withholding information, or by creating a monster which only he understands)?

Comment: The problem with tolerating a "brilliant asshole" is that when management finally grow a pair, they tend to find that the "briiliant" part was an illusion.

Comment: @FioratheFerret relative to my peers, they have the most experience working in that particular technology. 15+ years. I do think they are replaceable, but it is about finding the right person to replace them with.

Comment: @bobo2000 Don't confuse years of experience with expertise!

Comment: Yes they are an expert, can get complex work done quickly

Answer (score 15):

There is no way in turning this around. A better person would have not abused their position. A better company would have stopped the abuse. You have neither. They have abused their position *and it worked for them*. Why would they change?

The only way out of this is actually getting the rest of the team into a position to take over for this person. You can frame it as you want. Not wanting to have a bus factor of one. Cross training your team. Hire another expert for backup. Dissolve their unique selling point.

There is a good chance the company does not want that, because it costs money. Then you are really out of options. But you can try.

Comment: Yeah you are right. It’s too entrenched. My boss has told me to not rock the boat so I’m biting my tongue with certain characters